# Sonar job in Jenkins never terminates

Tags: plugins, jenkins, sonarqube, terminate

In a specific project built in Jenkins/Sonar, the build job never terminates.

In the console, we can see:

`[INFO] ... ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse ....`

`[INFO] ... Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob`

In every run, the build halts at the same line in the console. If we enter the sonar report, all information from the new build seems to be up to date.

Other projects works like a charm.

Any ideas about what might be wrong?

Comment: How big is this project? Can you include the Sonar log file for this analysis?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, also no clue what's causing it

Comment: same problem, build takes about 18h so it's a large project

Comment: We have a similar problem, but we use Gradle's sonarRunner plogin instead of the Jenkins plugin. Or Sonar job always ends with

    00:44:51.691 Total time: 31:06.238s
    00:44:52.294 Final Memory: 94M/1679M
    00:44:52.294 INFO:---------------------------------------------------------------------
    00:44:52.978 
    00:44:53.010 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    00:44:53.011 
    00:44:53.013 Total time: 44 mins 50.748 secs
    00:44:54.601 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS


(rotating animated GIF here forever)